# What sort of shared hosting can I run a JIRA installation on?

Tags: web-hosting, application

I purchased [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) a few weeks ago to manage some projects and such and intended to put it on my shared web host.

However, it requires a Tomcat server instead of Apache. It comes with a packaged Tomcat server, but when I use this, I get errors about exceeding my accounts memory and CPU limits.

Are there any shared hosting providers that can host JIRA successfully? How can I tell which ones will work?

Comment: This sounds more relevant to http://serverfault.com/ - WebApps is about using web applications, not installing & running them.

Answer (score 2):

I've never attempted to install or run JIRA on a shared server, but my guess is that most consumer-grade hosting providers would not be robust enough to handle JIRA. According to the [requirements](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/JIRA+Requirements), you can run it with 256MB RAM, but that's for a very bare-bones installation. Once you start getting lots of issues and users, etc., you'll easily need 1-2GB, which is pretty expensive in the VPS and shared-hosting world.

Comment: Agreed. I even tried a Rackspace Cloud server and the baseline one couldn't handle it. I'd have to use the $20/month server, which is just too much for me.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I am using Jira on a Win 2008 RS dedicated server. I'm looking to move it to another server so it's easier for me to let someone else maintain it.

You may want to look for a Linux VPS with 2GB of Ram